# Adding patches to axes in loop returns a ValueError

Tags: python, matplotlib, valueerror

So, I have a `for` loop that plots *creatures* in a figure's subplots. I'm using [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/grid-strategy) for subplot arrangement. Here is my code excerpt:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import numpy as np
from grid_strategy import strategies
from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString
from descartes.patch import PolygonPatch


fig = plt.figure()
space = [
    Circle((2, 2), radius=5, color='red',  alpha=np.random.uniform(0, 1)),
    Circle((-2, 2), radius=5, color='red',  alpha=np.random.uniform(0, 1)),
    Circle((2, -2), radius=5, color='red',  alpha=np.random.uniform(0, 1)),
]

lines = [
    [
        [0.0, 0.0],
        [0.007963267107332634, 9.999996829318349],
        [-9.992024050168064, 10.015923358483217]
    ],
    [
        [-9.992024050168064, 10.015923358483217],
        [-5.547622120022902, 3.3640595983538804],
        [-2.7450196155284288, 10.857084301489543]
    ],
    [
        [-2.7450196155284288, 10.857084301489543],
        [-8.83003187757613, 8.873999388852386]
    ],
    [
        [-2.7450196155284288, 10.857084301489543],
        [-1.1168525035132877, 0.9905209760275202]
    ],
    [
        [-9.992024050168064, 10.015923358483217],
        [-4.576474350758081, 15.904201668245792],
        [-9.381605405732934, 9.508053175245003]
    ],
    [
        [-9.381605405732934, 9.508053175245003],
        [-9.348197751236784, 15.907965981574565]
    ],
    [
        [-9.381605405732934, 9.508053175245003],
        [-15.091199417814586, 1.2982702172611962]
    ]
]

creature = MultiLineString(lines)

creature_patch = PolygonPatch(creature.buffer(5))

plot_spec = strategies.SquareStrategy('center').get_grid(2)

for _, sub in zip(range(2), plot_spec):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(sub)

    for line in creature:
        x, y = line.xy
        ax.plot(x, y, 'r-')

    ax.add_patch(creature_patch)
    for p in space:
        ax.add_patch(p)

ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.autoscale(axis='y')
ax.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

For a **single** iteration of the for loop it **works** and outputs the following:
[image: Creature with patches]

**Where:**
`for line in creature:` is the red lines
`ax.add_patch(creature_patch)` is the blue blob and
`for p in space:` is the red circles

However as soon as I want to plot multiple subfigures I get the following error:

```
  File "c:\Users\Zack\Google Drive\Studies\Meesters\Meesters\New Direction (L-Systems)\New-Direction-L-Systems-\Versions\tools\render.py", line 109, in genDraw
    ax.add_patch(p)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 1967, in add_patch
    self._set_artist_props(p)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 926, in _set_artist_props
    a.axes = self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 209, in axes
    raise ValueError("Can not reset the axes.  You are probably "
ValueError: Can not reset the axes.  You are probably trying to re-use an artist in more than one Axes which is not supported
```

which i don't understand because the `ax` variable is set to a different `Axes` object at each iteration.

Thank you for any help

Comment: `space` apparently contains several patches. Once you have added them to one axes, you cannot add them to another axes. This is what the error tells you.

Comment: `space` is a list of shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon objects. A copy of `space` for each iteration did not solve this.

Comment: It might depend on how you do the copy. But without [mcve] it's really hard to see what's going on. It doesn't look like creating such verifiable example would be too hard in this case.

Comment: The creature_list is the part that is a hassle to create... takes quite a while

Comment: To me the problem looks independent of `creature_list`. Just leave it out or replace it by some hardcoded list of objects.

Comment: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented already, `space` contains several patches. Once you have added them to one axes, you cannot add them to another axes. This is what the error tells you.

The solution is to create one set of patches per axes, e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()

def get_space():
    space = [
        Circle((2, 2), radius=5, color='red',  alpha=np.random.uniform(0, 1)),
        Circle((-2, 2), radius=5, color='red',  alpha=np.random.uniform(0, 1)),
        Circle((2, -2), radius=5, color='red',  alpha=np.random.uniform(0, 1)),
    ]
    return space


plot_spec = fig.add_gridspec(1,2)

for _, sub in zip(range(2), plot_spec):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(sub)

    for p in get_space():
        ax.add_patch(p)

    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.autoscale(axis='y')
    ax.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Aha! Great thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. In the actual case, space wat pickled earlier and loaded before the `for` loop. Now I simply load it inside the `for` loop. Thanks again!